# Why does my if statement appear to be running twice on first run, even though it shouldn't?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I am currently making a game similar to Flappy Bird, and I have an `if` statement nested inside another `if` statement. When the first `if` statement becomes `false`, the other `if` statement still runs, but it only runs once. It should not be running when the first `if` statement returns false.

```
void Update()
 {   
     if(!passed) {
         if(Player.position.x >= gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x) {
             Debug.Log("done");
             passed = true;
         }
     }
}
```

As you can see when it first starts, the passed boolean becomes `true` which means it shouldn't run again after completion. However when I pass the obstacle for the first time in-game, it prints out "done" twice. This only occurs for the first obstacle.

In another script I have this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision){
        GameObject.Find("ObstacleTop").GetComponent<Obstacles>().passed = false;

}
```

And btw passed is set to false at the start:

```
    public bool passed = false;
```

Comment: Is it hitting the  `update` method multiple times? Could it be that one thread is hitting it and returning return and another is hitting it and returning false

Comment: Use `transform.position.x` instead of `gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x`

Comment: I think you have the script on two game objects

Comment: @MiladQasemi Yes, I do have it on two game objects. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: There is nothing to fix it debug.log happens once for each game object so it happens twice in total

Comment: @MiladQasemi Instead of Debug.Log I want to add a value to the score. Will it add 2 points or does it only do that with Debug.Log?

Comment: Do you want to add two points or not?

Comment: @MiladQasemi I only want to add 1 point. I am making a flappy bird kind of game so when it goes through the obstacles I want to add 1 point

Comment: @Symet3 this is not a good way to make it but anyway if you have the script attached to multiple game objects it will happen for each one of them

Answer (score 2):

The script is probably attached to two game objects, so it shows the log output twice.

You can see which instance the log is for by calling `GetInstanceID()` in the Debug statement.

```
if (!passed) {
  if (Player.position.x >= gameObject.GetComponent < Transform > ().position.x) {
    Debug.Log(gameObject.GetInstanceID() + " done");
    passed = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the flag you use to indicate whether it passed or not is *not* in the same scope as its accompanying `if` statement, your logic will now depend on the *second* nested `if` statement instead.

If you want to only go through this once regardless of what happens in the body, you should do something like this instead:

```cs
void Update()
{   
     if(!passed) {
         if(Player.position.x >= gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x) {
             Debug.Log("done");
         }

         passed = true;
     }
}
```

This marks the block as passed *as long as it has entered there at least once*.

Comment: However passed is turning true before the player has passed the obstacle which means that it never runs again. So it didn't work

Comment: @Symet3 If this does not work, that means that your second condition `Player.position.x >= gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x` is wrong. Has nothing to do with the question you asked, nor you provided any code when the `Player` is initialized or if `Transform` component has correct value.

Comment: No because I am making a flappy bird kind of game so when the obstacles start getting closer to the player the update void is going to keep on running every frame and because passed is become true when if(!passed) is true then passed will become true immedietly when the game starts which means that the first if statement "if(!passed)" will not run afterwards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the code for the first object that ever executes `Update` and fulfills the condition, then make the `passed` variable static.

```cs
public static bool passed;

void Update()
 {   
     if(!passed &&
        Player.position.x >= gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x) {
             Debug.Log("done");
             passed = true;
     }
}
```

If you make the variable static, it will exist once for this class instead of once per instance (i.e., per object).

You can also combine the two if-statements. Since C# uses short circuit evaluation, the second part of the condition (after the `&&`) will not be evaluated, if the first part evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Hello, I unfortunately can't make it private static because I am using the bool in another script.

Comment: Then make it public static or introduce a second private static variable. Or use a property `public static bool Passed { get; private set; }`. If it is static you will have to access it through the class name instead of a variable.